# MouseOver doesn't bubble on overlapping divs?

Tags: javascript, css

Using jQuery 2.1, Meyer's 2.0 CSS [reset script](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), targeting IE9+ and modern browsers.

I've made two overlapping divs. I'm listening to `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on both of them. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbkjL/1/

Expected behaviour: mouseover events fire on both divs.

Actual behaviour: mouseover event fires only on the top div.

How can I make the mouseover event bubble to the bottom div?

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="below"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 $("#top")
     .mouseover(function () {
     console.log("top");
 })
     .mouseout(function () {
     console.log("top out");
 });

 $("#below")
     .mouseover(function () {
     console.log("bottom");
 })
     .mouseout(function () {
     console.log("bottom out");
 });
```

CSS

```
#top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
#below {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

Comment: future visitors: Also make sure you don't have any box-shadows or anything like that on children that makes parent to be triggered on parts that are not overlapping children.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the `mouseover` on `#below` to trigger `#top`'s one, make `#below` a child of `#top`.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="below"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your current HTML, there's no relation of bubbling nor capturing between your two divs, as they're not nested.

A reminder of bubbling /  from [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html):

> ### Event capturing
>
> When you use event capturing
>
> ```
>                | |
> ---------------| |-----------------
> | element1     | |                |
> |   -----------| |-----------     |
> |   |element2  \ /          |     |
> |   -------------------------     |
> |        Event CAPTURING          |
> -----------------------------------
> ```
>
> the event handler of element1 fires first, the event handler of
>   element2 fires last.
>
> ### Event bubbling
>
> When you use event bubbling
>
> ```
>                / \
> ---------------| |-----------------
> | element1     | |                |
> |   -----------| |-----------     |
> |   |element2  | |          |     |
> |   -------------------------     |
> |        Event BUBBLING           |
> -----------------------------------
> ```
>
> the event handler of element2 fires first, the event handler of
>   element1 fires last.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vbkjL/5/), let me know if I misunderstood you.

Comment: You have not misunderstood me, thanks for the help. :)